# cron.d script launching then dying

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell-script, cron

Many stack posts seem to suggest something like:

```
* * * * * root /usr/bin/pgrep -f 'socat -T10 TCP4-LISTEN:22222,fork UDP4:localhost:22223' || (/usr/bin/socat -T10 TCP4-LISTEN:22222,fork UDP4:localhost:22223 &)
```

Will work as a `cron` oneliner in a file (in e.g, `/etc/cron.d/mycron`) but it simply doesn't on Ubuntu 22.04 using the standard `cron`. It obviously works fine if I just execute it, or if I put it into a script file and then run the script file (with `bash` or `sh`, same thing) from cron.

```
* * * * * root /bin/sh /root/myscript.sh
```

From trying to get logging it looks like processes *are* being launched but then they are being killed afterwards. I have tried many different levels of bracketing, and with and without the `&` at the end. Nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: General advice: remember that cron runs in a different environment that your command line. Try changing the commands to be more verbose and look at the cron log OR just have the cron job spit out stdout and stderr to a file. I've been bitten by this problem many many times. My random guess: your LD_LIBRARY_PATH is different between cron and command line

Comment: @barrycarter I obviously ensured that it was using full paths and even setting the `SHELL=/usr/bin/bash` has no effect.

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is actually an environment variable, not a path for binaries. But if Kamil's answer works, that's cool too

Comment: @barrycarter I'm just not seeing why this is going to be affecting `pgrep` or `socat` - one or both of them might be failing because they can't find shared libraries? I would be very surprised to see that for these system-installed utilities

Comment: True, so I guess I'll fallback to my original point: cron runs things differently, so it's good to look at the stdout and stderr to see what's happening, assuming the cron logs themselves aren't helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Analysis

Your cron runs `sh -c …` where `…` denotes a single argument being the string you placed in the crontab after `* * * * * root` . This string obviously contains the pattern you're passing to `pgrep`. In effect `pgrep` finds at least this `sh` process and reports success, `socat` is not executed and the `sh` exits.

In case of `/bin/sh /root/myscript.sh` the argument after `sh -c` does not contain the pattern. This is why this method works.

Note the arguments of `pgrep` also match the pattern, but `pgrep` never reports itself as a match. If it did, it would be virtually useless. By using `pgrep` directly inside crontab you stage a situation where it always finds its parent (`sh`) and has no clue it shouldn't.

---

#### Solution

Use this line:

```
* * * * * root /usr/bin/pgrep -f '^socat -T10 TCP4-LISTEN:22222,fork UDP4:localhost:22223$' || (/usr/bin/socat -T10 TCP4-LISTEN:22222,fork UDP4:localhost:22223 &)
```

`^` at the beginning of a pattern matches the beginning, `$` at the end matches the end. Now only a command that is exactly `socat -T10 TCP4-LISTEN:22222,fork UDP4:localhost:22223` will match; `sh -c …` will not.

---

#### Simplification

I think in case of *this particular command* you can simply run it asynchronously every minute:

```
* * * * * root /usr/bin/socat -T10 TCP4-LISTEN:22222,fork UDP4:localhost:22223 &
```

The point is `socat` will exit if the port to listen on is taken. Cron won't see the failure though, because `whatever &` always returns exit status 0.

Note in general you cannot use this simplification blindly. The fact our `socat` exits automatically is crucial. A tool other than `socat` (or even `socat` with different arguments) started every minute may survive and accumulate. In general `pgrep` is useful.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Though I will confess that's what I understood the advantage of pgrep to be over normal grep (not finding itself), so obviously it's not actually that useful if you still have to check for these things!